# Security Rules for Firestore to allow access to all subcollections based on UID

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So trying to setup my firestore database and I have a collection called Users that stores the users information.  I also have subcollections of Towers for each user.  My users documents have a playerUid field that I use for security settings.  Here are my current security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{user=**}{
        allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.playerUid;
    }
  }
}
```

this allows users to read, create both their user document and the subcollection of tower documents, but they cant edit the subcollection.  There is no playerUid in the tower documents.  Is there a way to use the playerUid in the user document to authenticate for updating the towers? Or do I need to add a playerUid field to the tower documents to authenticate against

Answer (score 5):

You can `get` the user document in the rules of the `Towers` subcollection as shown in the [Firestore documentation on accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents):

> ```
> allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
> ```

Alternatively you can indeed include the UID if the user in the documents of the subcollection. That will prevent needing an extra document read in the rules.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet may be able to help you

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
        match /users/{user=**}{
            allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
          allow update: if request.auth.uid == user; // <== THIS LINE
        }
      }
    }
```

Wouldn't this match the 'user' path with the 'uid'?
I will try test this when I have some time.
It would save a get call if it does work.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how/why your code can help the OP to solve his problem

Comment: I have been trying something similar to this but I found out that the "user" variable contains the entire path not just the uid so this code won't work as it is. In my case I have been trying to split the user variable by "/" and then get the first index because that will equal the uid but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.